# wordpress template page error when select from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have take the page.php page and i have created a new template page named mytemplatepage.php
The page mytemplatepage.php works normally untill i try to add an sql query. when i add the bellow code the page gives http 500 error.

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
  $sqlresults = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT id, CategoryName
        FROM wp_SimParts"
        );
 ?>
```

if i remove the code and just leave

```
<?php
?>
```

the page load normally. if i put an echo on the php code the page again crashes with http 500 error

```
<?php
echo "hello there";
?>
```

--EDIT Error Log--
I am taking this error from logs

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'my_template_page' (T_STRING) in

Comment: Turn PHP errors on so you can see what the actual error is

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try like this.

You write below method on your template file.

```
function my_template_page() {
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "SELECT id, CategoryName FROM wp_SimParts";
  $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
  $page = (array) $pageposts ;
  if(!empty($page)) {
       return "Not Empty";
  } else {
       return "Empty";
  }
}
echo my_template_page();
```

If you get error then either you did mistake on header file content-type OR you need to update your WordPress. Your template file is fine.

Thanks

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'my_template_page' (T_STRING) in

Comment: when i echo i am taking this error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"hello there"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

error 500 is an internal server error, check all you closing tags in your mytemplatepage.php template page, also check your error log on the server.
It would help it you copy paste the error here

Comment: I don't think that's your PHP Error log, as there's nothing there to indicate what's causing the 500 error. Is this the access log you've got by mistake?